# Mongo, enforce a particular field in a collection has a unique value

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection: "foo"

```
foo: {name: 'steve'}
```

So to make the name a unique index you would run:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex( {{name: 1}}, { unique: true } )
```

However what I want to do is make sure that only ONE name with a value of 'steve' is allowed. Is there a way to make a field a unique index but specify that it should only enforce if the value of that property is of a certain value?

Pseudo query..... `db.foo.ensureIndex( {{name: 'steve'}}, { unique: true } )`

Good

```
foo: {name: 'steve');
foo: {name: 'chris'};
foo: {name: 'chris'};
foo: {name: 'mike'};
foo: {name: 'mike'};
```

Bad

```
foo: {name: 'steve');
foo: {name: 'steve'};
foo: {name: 'chris'};
foo: {name: 'chris'};
foo: {name: 'mike'};
foo: {name: 'mike'};
```

Comment: I'm not sure of any way to do this through indexing, but will be watching this question with curiosity. Might just have to handle this through the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really, **really** desperate, make your value a key:

```
db.uniq.insert( { "name" : {"steve" : null } }); 
db.uniq.insert( { "name" : {"john" : null } });

db.uniq.ensureIndex( {"name.steve" : 1}, {unique : true, sparse: true} );
```

Instead of `null`, you could use `1` or `"bogus"` or whatever. Just make sure it's always the same, and preferably small.

Note that the key **must** be unique *and* sparse, otherwise the missing `steve` field will be intepreted like `"steve" : null`. Because the sparse key is really only on  a single document, this solution isn't even particularly expensive I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply unfortunately I can't really change the code/values or I'll need to go through a bunch of red tape. Was hoping there was some usage of ensureIndex I wasn't aware of as a simple fix.